# Javascript sup() not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a script that takes a string, and whenever there is a letter, the next number is superscripted. To do this, I split the string into an array and loop through it - whenever I find a letter, I run sup() on the next array element.

JS

```
var ec = "1s2 2s4".split("");
for (var i = 0; i < ec.length; i++) {
    if (ec[i].match(/[a-z]/i)) {
        ec[i + 1].sup();
    }
}
```

But when I do this, nothing happens to the numbers I ran sup() on. Why is this?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yxj143az/7/

Comment: Those APIs like `.sup()` are a relic of bad 90's ideas about what JavaScript was for.  All `.sup()` does is surround the string with a `<sup></sup>` tag. That said, the functions return a new string; they don't change the original string. Strings are immutable.

Comment: Seems like a reg exp would be a better option.... `"1s2 2s4".replace(/s(\d+)/g, "s<sup>$1</sup>")`

Comment: `"1s2".blink()` yeah, don't do that. .... @epascarello OP is using `[a-z]` so I assume `s` is a single example, it could be any letter. `"1s2 2b4".replace(/([a-z])(\d+)/g, "$1<sup>$2</sup>");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just avoid using sup, here is a quick example of how to accomplish this:

```js
var ec = "1s2 2s4".split("");
for (var i = 0; i < ec.length; i++) {
    if (ec[i].match(/[a-z]/i)) {
        // I removed the call to sup, even though it is only deprecated
        // and has been for awhile it is still accessible. Feel free to
        // use it if you would like, i just opted not to use it.
        // The main issue with your code was this line because you weren't
        // assigning the value of your call to sup back to the original variable,
        // strings are immutable so calling on a function on them doesn't change
        // the string, it just returns the new value
        ec[i + 1] = '<sup>' + ec[i + 1] + '</sup>';
        // if you want to continue to use sup just uncomment this
        // ec[i + 1] = ec[i + 1].sup();

        // This is a big one that I overlooked too.
        // This is very important because when your regex matches you reach
        // ahead and modify the next value, you should really add some checks
        // around here to make sure you aren't going to run outside the bounds
        // of your array
        // Incrementing i here causes the next item in the loop to be skipped. 
        i++
    }
}

console.log(ec.join(''));
```

**EDIT/Update** based on some valid feedback in the comments I went back and commented the answer to illustrate exactly what I changed and why. Big thanks to @IMSoP for pointing this out to me.

Comment: I think this answer is slightly misleading, because the bug in the question is not the use of `.sup()`, but the fact that the result is not assigned back to the variable. You have changed both things, but only mentioned the less important one - it may be deprecated, but according to MDN it's still supported everywhere, even in node.js

Comment: @IMSoP Good catch

Answer (score 1):

The [`.sup()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sup) does not modify a string in place, it takes a string and returns a new string.

So instead of just running it...

```
 ec[i + 1].sup();
```

...you need to assign its result back to your string...

```
 ec[i + 1] = ec[i + 1].sup();
```

However, as pointed out by other users, the method should probably not be used any more, as it is considered "deprecated" and may be removed by browsers. Luckily, it's very simple to replace, because all it does is add `<sup>` and `</sup>` around the string, so you can rewrite the line without it:

```
 ec[i + 1] = '<sup>' + ec[i + 1] + '</sup>';
```